# I cannot let the list write in txt (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, console.writeline

I want to use writelines() to let the list write in txt, but after running, there's nothing in my txt. What's wrong with my code?

Help me if you could. Thank you!

example list(records):  [['flower', '200'], ['ham', '60'], ['van', '150']]

I want to write in the txt as below:

flower 200

ham 60

van 50

my code:

```
def save(initial_money, records): # I need both so don't change.
    with open('records.txt', 'w') as f: 
        first_line = str(initial_money) + "\n"
        f.write(first_line)
        return initial_money
        L = []
        for rec, amt in records:
            all_rec = str(rec) + " " + str(amt) + "\n"
            L.append(all_rec)
        f.writelines(records) # must use writelines
        return records
```

Comment: You return in the middle of the function **and** have the last return indented one step too much

Comment: move the `return` one TAB to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
def save(initial_money, records):
    with open('records.txt', 'w') as f: 
        first_line = str(initial_money) + "\n"
        f.write(first_line)
        for rec, amt in records:
            f.write(str(rec) + " " + str(amt) + "\n")
```

The first return closes the function, you don't need second return either, `records` is available as argument.

If you insist on using `writelines`, you can modify it like below:

```
def save(initial_money, records):
    with open('records.txt', 'w') as f: 
        first_line = str(initial_money) + "\n"
        f.write(first_line)
        L = []
        for rec, amt in records:
            L.append(str(rec) + " " + str(amt) + "\n")
        f.writelines(L)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I must use writelines in my homework... ;(

Answer (score 1):

I didn't succeed to understand what you need two arguments.

here is my code:

```
def save(initial_money,records):
    first_line = str(initial_money) + "\n"
    with open('records.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(first_line)
        for items in records:
            f.writelines(f"{items[0]} {items[1]} ")
            f.writelines('\n')

records = [['flower', '200'], ['ham', '60'], ['van', '150']]
initial_money = 0
save(initial_money, records)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have renewed my question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution isn't wrong but the other's is closer to my code what I want.I hesitated for 10 mins... Sorry